# How to iterate through the duplicates dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Hellow, everyone!
I have a CSV file, which contains only dublicates value from my main database. I have a three column(Year, Rate and Color), which need to be group. Color column is a Python-list in each cell

```
Name    Year    Rate    Color
Name1   2017    4.5     ['yellow', 'green', blue']
Name1   -       4.5     ['blue', 'green', yellow']
Name2   2019    5       ['pink', 'orange']
Name2   2019    -       ['pink', 'orange']
Name3   2018    4       ['blue', 'white', 'green']
Name3   2019    3       ['yellow', 'blue', 'white']
```

I need to group it in case of the same value. If we have the same year or Rate in every column of current Name, I need to take it value. And, if we have value in only one Name and other is '-', we take the year from cell, which contain it. With color, we need to take result in case of lists contain the same values. If we have difference in one of this column, we leave duplictes values with each values(like Name3) Expected result should be like this:

```
Name    Year    Rate    Color
Name1   2017    4.5     ['yellow', 'green', blue']
Name2   2019    5       ['pink', 'orange']
Name3   2018    4       ['blue', 'white', 'green']
Name3   2019    3       ['yellow', 'blue', 'white']
```

My question is, how to iterate through the duplicates value in this DataFrame and group value in case of non difference and leave it in different rows in case of difference?

Comment: What does it mean when a year or rate is `'-'`? The colours are going to be a bit more awkward, how many different ones are there in total? Does each row only have 2 or 3 colours?

Comment: About year and rate. It’s different column. And when we have, for example at Name1 in one case year ‘-‘ and in another - number, we should take number. About list, there may be different number of elements, we just need to compere two list

Comment: _Instead of NaN About list_ I'm not sure what you mean, but I was about to suggest that you use `NaN` here. _About list, there may be different number of elements, we just need to compere two list_ I know, I'm asking to figure out if there might be a better way of storing that data. Please see the questions I raised in my previous comment.

Comment: About 15000 colors, most of them have different names in each Name(but mean one color).

Answer (score 0):

You could group by the Rate variable and use [`aggregation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation):

```
df = df.groupby('Rate').agg({'Name':'first','Year':'first','Rate':'first','Color':'first'})
```

By doing this, we'll be able to keep the name and year variables and ignore any null or '-' values in the year and rate variables.

---

```
print(df)                                                              
       Name    Year  Rate                  Color
Rate                                            
3.0   Name3  2019.0   3.0  [yellow, blue, white]
4.0   Name3  2018.0   4.0   [blue, white, green]
4.5   Name1  2017.0   4.5  [yellow, green, blue]
5.0   Name2  2019.0   5.0         [pink, orange]
```